# Programa para gerar jogos e números da mega sena

Tags: java, array, random

Infelizmente não estou conseguindo gerar mais de um jogo de 6 números. O correto seria gerar a quantidade de jogos que o usuário digitaria e ficaria armazenada na variável `jogos`.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * AtividadeMegaSena
 */

public class AtividadeMegaSena {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Quantos jogos você quer fazer?");

    int jogos = teclado.nextInt();

    Random aleatorio = new Random();

    int[] numeros = new int[6];

    for (int i = 1; i <= numeros.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(aleatorio.nextInt(61));

    }

    teclado.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: O que é esse 61 aí?

Comment: era pra ser (60)+ 1 pra nao bugar,
é pq a mega sena os numeros que podem ser escolhidos vão de 1 à 60

Comment: Você pode usar uma matriz cuja primeira dimensão é a quantidade de jogos e a segunda o tamanho de cada jogo (6). E.g.,: `int[][] jogosGerados = new int[jogos][6];`. Embrulhe seu laço com outro laço externo iterando entre 0 e `jogos` (e.g., com um indice `j`). Após gerar os números atribua cada jogo a uma entrada na matriz, e.g., `jogosGerados[j] = numeros;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há pelo menos dois problemas aí. Um deles é o descrito e não tem um laço pra controlar o número de jogos, precisa criar isto, ele vai de 0 até logo antes do número digitado. O outro problema que esta forma pode dar números repetidos, o que não é permitido no tipo de algoritmo que deseja fazer. Então a melhor forma é gerar uma lista com os números possíveis (1-60) e mandar embaralhar, assim é garantido que não tem repetição, isto chama [algoritmo de embaralhamento Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
import java.util.*;

class AtividadeMegaSena {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Quantos jogos você quer fazer?");
        int numJogos = teclado.nextInt();
        List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) numeros.add(i);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numJogos; i++) {
            Collections.shuffle(numeros);
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) System.out.println(numeros.get(j));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zj7hFY). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ShuffleMega). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/ShuffleMega.java).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, amigo. Deu certo!